# PHP: A Class as a member inside another Class

Tags: php, oop

In my PHP project, I have 2 classes named `User` & `Category` as follows.

```
class User{
    public $Id;
    public $Name;
    public $Category;   
}

class Category{
    public $CategoryId;
    public $CategoryName;
}
```

My requirement is to include both `CategoryId` & `CategoryName` inside the `$Category` of the `User` when retrieving data.

So when I accessing a `User - object` I can get both `CategoryId` & `CategoryName` of the user.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

How to automate this process? When I want to load a `User` from the database, I want that `User` to load it's `Category` details **Automatically**.

And when I loading a collection of `User`s (or all Users from the database), I want that all Users to load their own Category.

Comment: can user class extend category ?

Comment: Thanx @vodich. Can I do this without extending?

Comment: Not that I can think of...

Comment: Of course it's possible.

Comment: @vodich Since when is a user a category????

Comment: @PeeHaa I was referring to class Category

Comment: @vodich I know what you were referring to, but that's not how it works. When a class extends another class it means that class A (`User`) **is a** class B (`category`).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle

Comment: I wasn't reading thorougly and just now saw that User has member $Category. Thanks for the info

Comment: @vodich My point was that a user should not extend category. Please read the link about the LSP a shared above :)

Comment: Yes,yes rectangle and square,getters and setters :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution that I wanted.

```
// user.php
<?php
require_once 'category.php';

class User{
    public $Id;
    public $Name;
    public $Category;   

    public function __construct(){
        $this->Category=Category::getCategory($this->Id);       
    }
}
?>

// category.php
<?php
class Category{
    public $CategoryId;
    public $CategoryName;

    public static function getCategory($UserId){
        $Category = //PDO operations;
        return $Category;
    }
}
?>
```

Thanks for everyone who replied.

Answer (score 2):

Of course, you can store a `Category` object inside of the `User`'s `$category` memeber:

```
$user = new User;
$cat = new Category;

$cat->categoryId = 42;
$cat->categoryName = "Meaning of Life";

$user->category = $cat;

//access
echo $user->category->categoryName; //Meaning of Life
```

Comment: Thanks @Madara. How to automate this process? When I want to load a `User` from the database, I want that `User` to load it's `Category` details **Automatically**.

Comment: @Seevali: Have a `loadCategory()` method on the `User` class which retrieves and create the category object, then assigns it to the field.

Comment: aside from "meaning of life" it also is a textbook case of someone violating *Law of Demeter*

Comment: and also, it breaks encapsulation, so it should only be used as an example